# Can I get FIDE titles (FM, IM, GM) by getting norms in blitz tournaments only?

Tags: fide, tournament, blitz, norm

Could I play in blitz tournaments only and get FIDE norms, hence I can get FIDÉ titles such as FM, IM, and GM?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

FIDE describe the rules for titles including in norms in the document [FIDE Title Regulations effective from 1 January 2022](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/B012022).

The first thing to note is that the FM title only requires reaching a certain rating. No norms are required for the FM and WFM titles:

> 1.3  Titles may be gained by achieving a published or interim rating at some time (see 1.53a).  For ratings achieved after 1st July 2017, the player must at that time have played at least 30 rated games:
>
> 1.3.1      **FIDE Master ≥2300**
>
> 1.3.2      Candidate Master ≥2200
>
> 1.3.3      Women FIDE Master ≥2100
>
> 1.3.4      Women Candidate Master ≥2000

Regarding the rates of play for all titles it says:

> 1.1.2     There must be no more than twelve hours play in one day. This is calculated based on games that last 60 moves, although games played using increments may last longer.
>
> 1.1.3 No more than 2 rounds shall be played on any one day.
>
> **Each player must have at least two hours in which to complete all the moves, assuming the game lasts 60 moves**.
>
> In the application for the GM or WGM title based on norms, at least one norm shall be achieved in a tournament with only one round per day for a minimum of 3 days.

So, no each player must have 2 hours, not 5 minutes, for all the moves assuming the game lasts 60 moves. That is standard time control not blitz.

Answer (score 9):

No you cannot. FIDE titles are only awarded for [classical chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIDE_titles).

Comment: Wikipedia didn't indicate that condition.

Comment: @salah First paragraph, second sentence under "Open titles" on Wikipedia: "*...a prescribed level of achievement in tournaments at classical time controls under FIDE-approved conditions.*"

Comment: Note that as Wikipedia pages can be edited by anybody at anytime it might be better to link to the references it uses, or other more stable sources.

Comment: @StackerLee 's point is key to understanding how and why Wikipedia is so accurate. Much research has been done to determine how accurate Wikipedia is, and it consistently scores better than the "professional" encyclopedias, but only because it links you directly to the source and how often people call out dubious claims. There is still much work to be done in making it even better, and while it's a great starting place, is no substitute for official sources!